# how to make layered UI using android studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

[How to make layers(like in image) on an activity's XMl in android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIiWu.png)

Backgroud is grey,on top of that there is a white layer.

Comment: you make its in a list or simple layout?

Comment: The above pic is a screenshot from amazon app.I want to know how to make that white foreground(like a cardview) on grey background.

Comment: set your list background color (Grey) and set your item background as color (White)

Answer (score 1):

Well in that picture , that consists of a scroll view as parent and linear layout as child. In linear layout you can implement grid layout with required attributes

Comment: i'm a beginner in android programming.How can i make different sections(white portion in above pic) on grey background

Comment: This is nota tutorial website , so if you need any kind of help in learning  I suggest to visit udacity